# Jquery action within a div to control another with load()

Tags: jquery, load, append

I have an index page `index.php`, and when the user clicks on a project (for the sake of this question, lets say that project is contained on an html page called `aeffect.html`), it loads `aeffect.html` into a div:

```
<div id="popupContainer"></div>
```

which is contained oncontained on `index.php`.

However, there are many projects on `index.php`, and each of these projects has a close button. I tried to use this variable to empty out `popupContainer` in hopes that it would reset it to empty, and `aeffect.html` would dissappear.

```
//Close property
$("a.close").click(function(){
    $("#popupContainer").empty();
});
```

This doesn't seem to work, I am not exactly sure how to make this work. Is there a way to make it so that the action from `aeffect.html` can control the div on `index.php`?

Here is the full jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Find & Open
$(".projectThumb").click(function(){
        $("#popupContainer").load("/aeffect.html");
            });

//Close property
$("a.close").click(function(){
    $("#popupContainer").empty();
        });
});
```

Here is the html for index.php

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="projectThumb">
    <img src="/img/aeffect_button_static.gif" width="146" height="199" class="button" name="aeffect" alt="" />
    <p class="title">A.EFFECT: Film Poster</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popupContainer"></div>
```

and the html for aeffect.html

```
<div class="projectPopup" id="aeffect">
    <a class="close">Close &times;</a>
    <img src="/img/aeffect_popup.jpg" width="500" height="729" alt="" />
    <p class="description">Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$('a.close').click()` handler is being added to all `a.close` elements *when `index.php` loads*.  This means that the `a.close` in the loaded content does not have the handler attached.

Either attach the handler after loading the new content, or use `$('a.close').live('click', ...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Strager,

I added modified the code to read 

$("a.close").live("click", function(){
   $("#popupContainer").empty();
   });

And that did the trick!